# Regular expressions - Matching comments

Tags: regex, comments, pattern-matching

I need to match this type of comments:

```
{This is a comment}
```

The comments can containt line breaks.

I have tried and have come upp with this regular expression:

```
\{(.|[\r\n])*\}
```

The problem is that this regexp matches everything between two comment, eg:

```
{comment}

text

{comment}
```

In the case above, text will also be matched.

How can I fix this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Using `?` make your regex pattern non-greedy (lazy) >>

```
\{[\s\S]*?\}
```

Note: `[\s\S]` is same as `(?:.|\n|\r)` or `(?:.|[\n\r])` or `[.\n\r]` ... matches **anything**

Comment: Not quite: the `.` in `[.\n\r]` matches a literal `.`.